# How to change pageview from within a page itself

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

I have a pageview that has my bottom nav and stuff on one file with the pagecontroller and I use this to navigate within my app. I have one page that transitions into another page essentially and passes data along to the new page, so I have Page 1 thats within a pageview with a button that passes data to a new page and opens it, how can I change to the new page without loosing the bottom app bar? as on Page 2 when I now click the back button at top left it pushes page 1 so I loose the app bar and causes a loop only being able to navigate between page 1 and 2,

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: mobileBackgroundColor,
    title: const Text('Page 1'),
    centerTitle: false,
  ),
  //Show 2 buttons for setting lost status
  body: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
    children: [
      //First button for setting status to Lost
      InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          /////
          Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => DetailsScreen(status: appStatus),
            ),
          );
        },
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Card(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(90.0),
              ),
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Container(
                width: 150,
                height: 150,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      child: const Icon(
                        Icons.report_rounded,
                        size: 50,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const Center(
              child: Text(
                'Broke',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18,
                  color: primaryColor,
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      //Second button for setting status to found
      InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          //
          Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => DetailsScreen(status: Status),
            ),
          );
        },
```

page 2 appbar

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return scanning == 'scanning'
    ? Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: mobileBackgroundColor,
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.arrow_back,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => const StatusScreen(),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
          title: const Text('Scanning'),
          centerTitle: false,
        ),
```

So I want to be able to navigate to page 1 from my app bar and enter the details i need then on tap travel to page 2, I have this working but since I use .push() as Im transfering the data back and forth between page 1 and 2 it causes page 1 to open as a push and creates a loop.

Comment: do you mean just changing the page

Comment: Yeah im trying to change the page within the pageview but still be able to pass data inbetween the pages, when I try to use push it creates a loop

Comment: Maybe you can just stay on single route and change the pages

Comment: How would I do that? I originally just had conditional rendering for the page but it got so long and complicated i,m now trying to split it up

Comment: Page 1 is basically the start of a complex form that can be accessed from the navbar using pageview, I want to be able to continue onto the next page of the form but still allow the user to go back and change data without losing any while keeping navbar and such